# Maintain button submit value when using link to submit a form

Tags: javascript, forms

i am trying to create a link that submits a form. I use this and works fine :

```
<a name="submit" href="javascript:document.theForm.submit();" class="rollover-button gray small"><span>Send Message</span></a>
```

However, i have a problem. My previous submit button was :

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Message" />
```

When this was clicked, i was getting a $_POST['submit'] value that i was checking with isset in my php script, to see whether the form is submitted or not. However, this does not work with my submit link. Does anybody know how i can do that ?

EDIT:

I tried that, as suggested :

```
<form action="." name="theForm" class="contactForm" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="Send Message" />

</form>

<a name="submit" href="javascript:document.theForm.submit();" class="rollover-button gray small"><span>Send Message</span></a>
```

But still does not work.

Comment: Why aren't you using the submit button? It doesn't make sense to use javascript to replace built-in browser functionality. Anyway, calling a form control "submit" shaddows the form's submit method so you can't call it, i.e. `document.theForm.submit` references the button, not the method.

Comment: It's because i have some styles that i want to use and only relate to links and not buttons. Not everything is about raw functionality :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create input type of hidden and check for its existence:

```
if (isset($_POST['hiddenName'])) {....}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hidden field instead. So when the form is submitted, you can check if the hidden element exists.

Like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="Send Message" />
```

This way, you can check for $_POST['submit'] when you submit the form. Just make sure the hidden <input> is *inside* the <form> element, so it will POST with the rest of the form.

Answer (score 0):

add a hidden input.

```
<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="Send Message" />
```

it will not be visible to the user, but it will be send with the form contents.

Comment: -1 - a form control with a name "submit" will shaddow the form's submit method so you can't call it.

Comment: @RobG You're correct. I was answering without thinking of all the implication. But still, my answer is valid because this was not the issue OP was asking. OP should change the input name to name="formsubmitted" and then check for $_POST['formsubmitted'] in his PHP code.

Comment: 1. remove the name="submit" from your <a> tag 
2. rename your hidden input to name="somethingelse" and check for $_POST['somthingelse'] in your PHP code
3. and put an action="" to your form, mate

Answer (score 0):

You can always hide the submit button (with css `display: none`) and click it with JavaScript:

```
document.forms.theForm.elements.submit.click();
```